# Allow text (or image) to exceed bottom margin by a bit

Tags: margins, page-breaking, minipage, geometry, text

I would like some text, image, or whatever, to be allowed to run into the bottom margin, for one page (or environment) only. I would like to keep this simple, and maintain consistent paragraph spacing and indenting (if text).

I'm using KOMA-Script and the geometry package. I've tried `\newgeometry`, but that requires requisite knowledge of the existing geometry. (Note that I maintain a format file for my colleagues, so pre-existing knowledge of the geometry parameters should be avoided). I've trid `\samepage` in the past with little success.

Of course, I'll be using this sparingly only on pages without footnotes. Just to squeeze maybe one, or two line of text in, and maybe 0.5cm of image. However, It seems that with my current solution, I can only squeeze one line until it breaks. A solution where I could set a threshold would be cool.

I have the following solution which appears okay, but it is very hacky. I use `\medskip` to achieve my paragraph spacing (`parskip=half*` in KOMA), which I do not trust are identical. I also need to manually input the indentation distance, which I'd like to avoid.

If you have any suggestions to set one on the right track, that'd be appreciated.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt,
twoside=false,
letterpaper,
parskip=half*,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{2ex}  % paragraph indent

\begin{document}

%%% WHAT HAPPENS
\vspace*{17ex}

\blindtext[2]

New paragraph here. You'll see that with this long sentence, this line wants to go on a new page.

\newpage


%%% WHAT I WANT (but consistent spacing with rest of document)
\vspace*{17ex}

\blindtext[2]

%\vspace{\parskip}  % does not work
\medskip  % I want to use the paragraph skip length, i believe this is inconsistent
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    {\hspace*{2ex} % \parindent wouldn't work?
New paragraph here. You'll see that with this long sentence, this line wants to go on a new page, but stays! It will break if any longer
}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\enlargethispage`? Or is it an instrument too blunt for your needs?

Comment: That seems to work as I desire and very simply, thank you. I was off-put by the command name and thought it would enlarge in more than one dimension, or scale the content. Another solid case for RTFM.

Comment: “There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.”